# OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow - "user hasn't approved this consumer"

Tags: oauth2, authorization, jwt

I am trying to get JWT Bearer Token Flow to work. But get the error *user hasn't approved this consumer*. I have read these posts:

[Salesforce JWT User Hasn't Approved This Consumer (Again)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184363/salesforce-jwt-user-hasnt-approved-this-consumer-again)

[OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30596/oauth-2-0-jwt-bearer-token-flow)

[OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow giving a user hasn't approved this consumer error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/31969/oauth-2-0-jwt-bearer-token-flow-giving-a-user-hasnt-approved-this-consumer-erro)

and all seem to say the same, that the application needs to be authorized. I am doing this, but still get the error. Is there something else that I am missing?

**Authorize**

```
POST https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: login.salesforce.com
Content-Length: 151
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

response_type=code&client_id=3MV...4QJ3&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost
```

**JWT Request**

```
POST https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: login.salesforce.com
Content-Length: 666
Expect: 100-continue

grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=eyJhbGciOiJ...pjCY1Ug
```

**JWT Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Sat, 10 Feb 2018 13:40:45 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests 
Cache-Control: no-cache,must-revalidate,max-age=0,no-store,private
Set-Cookie: BrowserId=A1Sl9NmzQ5eoVt_etmmBbg;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Wed, 11-Apr-2018 13:40:45 GMT;Max-Age=5184000
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 82

{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"user hasn't approved this consumer"}
```

Comment: What are the scopes you've selected for your connected app? (api + refresh_token/offline_access seem to both be required.) Are you using the same user for the JWT as you are for authroizing? Do you need users to self-authorize (having an admin mark certain profiles as pre-authorized makes the JWT flow a bit easier at the cost of a little security).

Comment: Also, you can check to see if your authorization attempt actually went through by checking a few places. If authorization did succeed, you should see a session for your specified user in the "User Session Information" page (setup menu -> search for "session management"). You should also see your connected app in the "OAuth connected apps" related list of your user's detail page.

Comment: Changing from *All users must self-authorize* to *Admin approved users are pre-authorized* did the trick. Thanks for that! I guess this is the option I should go with since the integration is from another system. But let's say I wanted to go with *All users must self-authorize*. What would I have to do?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, since I've only ever used the pre-authorized setting myself. That's why I was asking questions and pointing you to places where you could check to see if the user-driver authorization had actually worked. The other questions you linked suggest that you need to first use a flow that generates a refresh token  (user-agent, or web server flows).

Answer (score 2):

"user hasn't approved this consumer" This is a common error caused when the user doesn't have a prior refresh_token associated with him/her.

The solution is to perform an Autorization grant (Web Server flow or User-Agent Flow) at least once. I wrote in detail about it; look **specifically at step #3** here - https://mannharleen.github.io/2020-03-03-salesforce-jwt/

That should solve the error.

Comment: Thanks for the link - but I may have found an errata on it as Salesforce has changed. You say to click edit against your app and then "Choose ‘Permitted Users’ = ‘Admin approved users are pre-authorized’
Save ."

but "Choose Permitted Users" does not appear on the app edit page.

Answer (score 0):

Just a brief addition, as I'm sure the OP has resolved this issue long ago by now. It may be helpful for others in the future.

I had the same issue, while was working in a sandbox

- created my Connected App
- built the JWT token via Python 3, PyJWT
- sent the requests via Python 3, requests

Each piece seemed to be perfectly fine but got back the `{'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': "user hasn't approved this consumer"}` error every time regardless any (pointless) effort.

For me, the [OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow giving a user hasn't approved this consumer error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/31969/oauth-2-0-jwt-bearer-token-flow-giving-a-user-hasnt-approved-this-consumer-erro) solution worked perfectly fine.

It seems the OP tried to send the authentication via Curl or HTTP client but in fact, it should be opened in a browser.

`https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[clientId]&redirect_uri=[redirectUri]&response_type=code`

where the `[clientId]` is the connected app `Consumer Key` and the `[redirectUri]` is the `Callback URL`. Of course, the domain should be correct for the type of environment the app is running (test.salesforce.com for sandbox, etc.)

When the URL is opened in a browser Salesforce.com - after login - will open up a page similar to this to review and accept the scopes of the requested app.

[image: SF connected app auth]

This wouldn't work with a command-line app (curl, http, etc)